# Simple Math Equations in Android App

Tags: math

This is my first time posting, and after trying several different versions of solutions, I'm at the point where I think what I'm asking for is a bit beyond what I'm able to do at this point.

I am currently creating a simple app for my company that will be used as a sales tool. In my industry, it would be immensely helpful for the salesman in the field to be able to enter dimensions to get quick quotes for the customer.

What I am looking to try and do is to have a text field that will allow the salesperson to enter L (length), W (width), and D (depth).

Behind the scenes (java) the L would go through a simple math equation that takes into account predetermined allowances. The answer would then be put into a results area that would let them know the blank size of the project.

ex. L = 8.0625 ---> ((D*2)+.125)*2 + L ---> Blank Length = 14.625

I realize that may seem a little confusing, but it really is just supposed to be a simple equation that uses user entered information, adding to a static equation, and then posting the results on the same page.

EDIT: I solved aspects of it, but now I'm getting a crash as I try to go from whole numbers to decimals. I can do 6 as an input, but not 6.25. Any advice?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_test4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.design.test4">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Length"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/length1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="Enter" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="Width"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/width1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="Enter" />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="Depth"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/depth1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="Enter" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:text="B Flute"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick1" />

    <Button
        android:text="C Flute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick2" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="Blank Width"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/depth1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/blank_width1" />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="Blank Length"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/blank_length1" />

    </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>







@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test4);
}

double ba_width = (2.625);
double ba_length = (.625);


public void onButtonClick1(View v){
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.length1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.width1);
    EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.depth1);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blank_width1);
    TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blank_length1);
    double num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    double num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    double num3 = Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
    double sum1 = num1 + (num3 + num3 + ba_width);
    double sum2 = num2 + (num3 + num2 + num3 + num2 + num3 + ba_length);
    t1.setText(Double.toString(sum1));
    t2.setText(Double.toString(sum2));
}

double ca_width = (3.25);
double ca_length = (.6875);


public void onButtonClick2(View v) {
    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.length1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.width1);
    EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depth1);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blank_width1);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blank_length1);
    double num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    double num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    double num3 = Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
    double sum1 = num1 + (num3 + num3 + ca_width);
    double sum2 = num2 + (num3 + num2 + num3 + num2 + num3 + ca_length);
    t1.setText(Double.toString(sum1));
    t2.setText(Double.toString(sum2));
}

}
```

Comment: What part is causing you problems? Presenting the text fields? Or doing the maths?

Comment: A bit of both to be honest. I have the general gist of how to get the input fields in place, but I'm having issues redirecting the input to display the text on the page after running through the equation.

Comment: ... then your question is not focused enough and should be closed as "too broad". Learn how to work with forms in your chosen Android dev framework. If this raises a **specific** question for SO, feel free to ask it. Likewise, if you have a **specific** question about doing maths in Java, ask that. FWIW I can't work out what you're asking wrt the maths anyway.

Comment: Why not have three text boxes, one for each dimension?  Why should the salesperson have to know about allowances?

Comment: Well there would be three text boxes, with each providing a different dimension for them to enter. If the customer said they needed L=6, W=4, and D=2, then the salesperson could enter this into the fields.

The "solution" would then be displayed as the blank size for that item, which would vary depending on the box. I just need help figuring out how to make the general equation of "L+1.3125+(D*2)" and put the solution into the right place. (1.3125 would be allowances for this box)